# How to add a vline between histogramm bars created with scale_x_binned

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since v3.3.0, `ggplot2` [provides binned scales](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#new-bin-scale) that allow discretize continuously values aesthetics on the fly and reflect that discretization in the asthetic's `guide`. For the latter feature, I prefer using `geom_bar` with a `scale_x_binned` over using `geom_histogram` for visualizing a continuous distribution.

However, when I try visualize e.g. a to-be-used threshold with `geom_vline` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

iris |> ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_binned(breaks = seq_len(100), limits = \(limits) c(floor(limits[1]), ceiling(limits[2])) ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=6, color="red") +
  NULL
```

[image]

The `vline`'s `xintercept` is discretized as well and thus appearing at another than the intended position. How can I avoid that and achieve something like this:

[image]

I have tried adding `, position=position_nudge(x=0.5)`) but it just warns:

> #> Warning in geom_vline(xintercept = 6, color = "red", position = position_nudge(x
> #> = 0.5)): Ignoring unknown parameters: `position`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a open FR](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4285) to add the `position` parameter to `geom_vline`. In the meantime, to work around this limitation of `geom_vline`, you can either create the layer directly:

```r
iris |> ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_binned(breaks = seq_len(100), limits = \(limits) c(floor(limits[1]), ceiling(limits[2])) ) +
  layer(geom= GeomVline,  stat = StatIdentity, position=position_nudge(x=0.5), params = list(color="red", xintercept=6)) +
  NULL
```

Or make use of `stage`d aesthetic mappings (make sure you use this within `aes(` `)`!):

```r
iris |> ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_binned(breaks = seq_len(100), limits = \(limits) c(floor(limits[1]), ceiling(limits[2])) ) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=stage(6, after_scale = xintercept+0.5)), color="red") +
  NULL
```

Both options will result in:

[image]

There might be a better way to solve the original problem that does not involve manually undoing the binning transformation or that at least doesn't require knowing the introduced shift ahead of time, so I'll leave this question open for a bit.